# Sending URL with unique parameters for each user

Tags: php, encryption, random, hash

I have  a users DB and I want to send an email for the users which will contain some unique parameters.

I have the user id, email, name and 2 fields in store these unique parameters in the DB.

I'm thinking of using both id and email to create the two parameters to be unique, Like using a hash/encryption/shuffle.

Like `md5`(I know it's not secured, But that's not for a password), `uniquid`, ..etc.

```
$uniquId = uniquid( $id );
$uniquEmail = md5( $email );

$URL = 'www.example.com/page.php?u='.$uniquId.'&e='.$uniquEmail;
```

In `page.php`:

```
$id = $_GET['u'];
$email = $_GET['e'];

//Check if these values exist in the DB, If exists show the page, Else redirect the user
```

But what if that random string contains `&Ugeb=kijd`, Then the URL would look something like : `www.example.com/page.php?u=26737&e=IKd752&uTehD=Hye3`, Then the `$_GET['e']` would be `IKd752` only right?

If so, What are the best ways to create the 2 unique parameters?

Comment: simply to str_replace to remove all & and = characters in the result string

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `time()` function to get a unique integer then you can multiply that with a constant just to make the number long or something. The only problem with this method is that your key will have numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Str_replace (like the 1st commenter suggested) and str_split to remove your unwanted strings.